# Django: validating hidden input

Tags: html, django, forms, hidden-field

I am currently in need of some advice regarding best practices when it comes to validating hidden input.

My situation requires me to connect some objects, and I have a form with some fields that provide information about how these should be connected. Though, I also need to know which objects to connect, and I thought best to do this using hidden input. There will be two hidden input fields, both providing pk's, integers. These will not be generated through by the form - I will write the HTML manually.

Now, my idea for validating that no tampering is done to these hidden input fields is this: I will add two integer-fields to the form, two fields that will  not be rendered at all, that share the names of the hidden input fields. Hopefully, this would mean that the hidden fields are validated just like all the other fields when run:

```
form = my_form(request.POST)      # request.POST containing hidden-fields as well 
form.is_valid():
```

Would this be a relatively safe way of checking that nothing else than integers are passed via the hidden input? Would this be as safe as normal form processing? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Django will validate an IntegerField whether or not the form field is hidden. The value in `request.POST` is the same either way. But are you sure you need the hidden inputs? How do you get the values when you render the hidden inputs? Perhaps you can get the values in the same way when you process the form.

Comment: Well the form is rendered several times, once for each user in a filtered query set: {% for user in users %} type of scenario. But this should be alright then, you reckon? @Alasdair

Comment: As I said, the Django will validate the field whether or not its a hidden input. Note that if it's a user id then you want to validate that the id is in the queryset `users`, not just that it's an integer. What you're doing sounds similar to [model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets).